# Calculate percentage using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find how I can calculate Percentage from table below

[image]

From the above table, I am hoping to get the data with percentage like below. However my SQL statement below returns all percentage value to 0. Please advise what I missed. Thanks

```
Select SupplierID
    , ProductID
    , Month
    , Year
    , Count(SupplierID) AS TotalSales
    , (count(SupplierID)* 100/(Select Count (*) From ProductOrder)) AS Percentage     
From ProductOrder
Order by Year DESC, Month DESC
```

[image]

Comment: @Dale K, Noted. I will do next time. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's integer division. Both operands to the division are integers, so the result is given as integer as well; `3/4` is `0`, not `0.75`. To work around this, just turn one of the arguments to a decimal.

I would also recommend using window functions rather than a subquery:

```
select supplierid, month, year, 
    count(*) as totalsales, 
    100.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over(partition by month, year) as percentage
from productorder
group by supplierid, month, year
order by year desc, month desc, supplierid
```

Notes:

- your original code is not a valid aggregation query to start with: it is missing a `group by` clause
- your sample data indicates that you want the ratio per supplier against the total of the month and year, while your query (attempts to) compute the overal ratio; I fixed that too